# Using class prefix pattern with css module

Tags: css, reactjs, less, css-modules

I have a general component that follows this pattern:

```
const Example = ({
  clsPrefix = '',
}: props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={`${clsPrefix}__div1`}>div 1</div>
      <div className={`${clsPrefix}__div2`}>div 2</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

The project is transitioning to using css module gradually. While this pattern does well with global css names, I couldn't get it to work with css modules. Namely:

```
// css module
.item {
  ...
  &__div1 {
    ...
  }
  &__div2 {
    ...
  }
}
```

```
// .tsx using css module
<Example clsPrefix={styles.item}/>
```

On the level of `Example` component, it couldn't get the unique identifier that gets appended to each class name. It doesn't work either to pass the whole `styles` object down. Is this just a bad pattern (`clsPrefix`) to style generalized component? How should I approach this problem with css module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with passing the whole css module object down to its child component and felt happy with this:

```
type StyleProps = {
  div1: string
  div2: string
}

type Props = {
  extraStyles?: Partial<StyleProps>
}

const Example = ({ extraStyles }: Props) => {

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={classNames({
          ...
          [extraStyles?.div1]: extraStyles?.div1,
        })}
      >
        div 1
      </div>
      <div
        className={classNames({
          ...
          [extraStyles?.div2]: extraStyles?.div2,
        })}
      >
        div 2
      </div>
    <>
  )
}
```

It's not the exact same pattern does the job as well - enabling overwriting bare-bone components with css modules.